# AngularJS controller using $interval not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular controller that is working in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox. I have searched around a bit but have not seen a solution to my particular problem. The goal is simple - a clock that updates every 1 second to the current time and refreshes using $interval. Has anyone seen a fix? Code below:

app.js:

```
app.controller('TimeCtrl', function($rootScope, $interval) {
$interval(function() {
    $rootScope.date = new Date();
    var currentTime = $rootScope.date;
}), 100;
});
```

index.html:

```
    <div ng-controller="TimeCtrl" class="large-12 time">
        <h1>
            {{date | date:'h:mm:ss a'}}</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
app.controller('TimeCtrl', function($rootScope, $interval) {
  $interval(function() {
    $rootScope.date = new Date();
    var currentTime = $rootScope.date;
  }, 100); // 100 needs to be your second parameter to the interval constructor
});
```